# Use of Data.Mod for modular exponentiation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, modular-arithmetic

When using `powMod`from the [Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Modular](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.12.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Modular.html) library, the Haskell compiler or interpreter gives the following warning:

> warning: [-Wdeprecations]
> In the use of ‘powMod’
> (imported from Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Modular):
> Deprecated: "Use Data.Mod or Data.Mod.Word instead"

I had the following function:

```
cypher n e m = powMod m e n
```

So I try to convert it to the recommended new library Data.Mod, substituting the `powMod` function by the `(^%)` operator:

```
cypher n e m = m ^% e :: Mod n
```

But then, the following error arises, and I don't know how to correct it:

> ```
> • Couldn't match expected type ‘Mod n1’ with actual type ‘p2’
>     because type variable ‘n1’ would escape its scope
>   This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
>     an expression type signature:
>       forall (n1 :: GHC.Types.Nat). Mod n1
>     at RSA-cyphering.hs:43:26-30
> • In the first argument of ‘(^%)’, namely ‘m’
>   In the expression: m ^% e :: Mod n
>   In an equation for ‘cypher’: cypher n e m = m ^% e :: Mod n
> ```

How can be used the type `Mod n` inside a function when the module `n` is taken from an argument to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`SomeMod`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.12.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli-Class.html#t:SomeMod):

```
cypher :: Natural -> Integer -> Integer -> SomeMod
cypher n e m = (m `modulo` n) ^ e
```

Comment: Ok, `powSomeMod` then, and the functions for "Unknown modulo" from Math.NumberTheory.Moduli.Class. Then I understand that Data.Mod can only be used for modulo which is known at coding time, because `Mod n` is a type and it can not be created dynamically inside a function at execution time, is this correct?.

Comment: @enrique You can use `powSomeMod` if you want, but `(^)` also works, is more readable, and magically becomes `powSomeMod` when optimizations are on, so I'd stick with the code as suggested here. Yes, `Mod n` can only be used directly when `n` is known at compile time; but `SomeMod` is an existential wrapper around `Mod n` that lets you create a `Mod n` dynamically inside a function at execution time.

Comment: But my original function gives an `Integer` (or any `Integral`). How can I get it from a `SomeMod` value? (what pattern matching?).

Comment: @enrique Have you read the documentation? What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: ``SomeMod c = (m `modulo` n) ^ e  -- Should give a (Mod m) value.``

Comment: The previous does not work, but I think I got it now, this gives an `Integer`:  ``cypher n e m = case (m `modulo` n) of SomeMod k -> getVal $ k ^% e``